# Execute php on Apache inside Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, virtual-host

I installed Ubuntu on VMWare (OS X) and followed the instructions to install [LAMP on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04) I also created a virtual host named 'cmsms23'. So the folder structure is:

> /var/www/cmsms23

I made the according conig file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/cmsms23.conf which contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@cmsms23
ServerName cmsms23
ServerAlias cmsms23
DocumentRoot /var/www/cmsms23
<Directory /var/www/cmsms23>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

~

If I enter 'php -version' the server response with:

> PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2019 12:07:07) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

If I make an html-file in the folder mentioned, that it executes according. However, if I want to display the phpinfo() via a simple php-file, than this file is not executed.

I search numerous site for a solution and tried several of them, but so far no luck. Anyone willing / able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use PHP in an HTML file.  In my experience using apache2/httpd, to use ANY PHP, the file had to have a .php extension.  The HTML still displayed fine, but PHP code wouldn't run for me unless I had a .php extension.

Comment: To clarify, the php code does have the php extension. The html code does have the html-extension.

Comment: So all the files containing PHP code are .php?

Comment: Yes, all files do have the appropriate extension.